# How to save same image with different names in PHP?

Tags: php, thumbnails

I have written a function for creating a thumbnail from .jpg image. But what I want to do is whenever the function gets called, same image should be saved as 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg at the same destination.

I have used Sessions and static variable concept but to no success.

Here is my code.
**this is thumbsave.php file**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['sid']=$k=1;
function createThumb($fpath)//fpath will be passed here as parameter.
{
$ims = imagecreatefromjpeg($fpath);
$imd = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

imagecopyresized($imd, $ims, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, imagesx($ims), 
imagesy($ims));
imagejpeg($imd,"saveimages/" . $_SESSION['sid'] . ".jpg");
$_SESSION['sid'] = $_SESSION['sid'] + 1;
imagedestroy($ims);
imagedestroy($imd);

echo "Thumbnail Created and Saved at the Destination";

}

?>
```

**Here is my code for dynamicthumb.php**

```
<?php
include("include/thumbsave.php");
createThumb("imgs/m1.jpeg");
 ?>
```

So,when I run the dynamicthumb.php file the image stored at the imgs folder must be stored inside saveimages folder. But here only 1 image is saved, not multiple copies are generated like 2.jpg,3.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a file_exists loop if you are positive the name of the thumbnail will always be numerical:

```
function createThumb($fpath)
{
    $ims = imagecreatefromjpeg($fpath);
    $imd = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

    imagecopyresized($imd, $ims, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, imagesx($ims), imagesy($ims));

    $thumb = 1;
    while ( file_exists('saveimages/'. $thumb .'.jpg') ) { $thumb++; }

    imagejpeg($imd,'saveimages/'. $thumb .'.jpg');
    imagedestroy($ims);
    imagedestroy($imd);

    echo 'Thumbnail Created and Saved at the Destination as '. $thumb .'.jpg';
}
```

However I question the logic behind what you are asking for... as this suggests that every thumbnail you create will just be a sequential number, all stored in the same directory?

You may have better luck using a `counter` db field or file, as doing `file_exists` on a folder with thousands and growing, can hurt performance.

So a file based `counter` solution could be thus:

```
function createThumb($fpath)
{
    $ims = imagecreatefromjpeg($fpath);
    $imd = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

    imagecopyresized($imd, $ims, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, imagesx($ims), imagesy($ims));

    $thumb  = file_get_contents('saveimages/thumbcount.txt');
    $thumb++; file_put_contents('saveimages/thumbcount.txt',$thumb);

    imagejpeg($imd,'saveimages/'. $thumb .'.jpg');
    imagedestroy($ims);
    imagedestroy($imd);

    echo 'Thumbnail Created and Saved at the Destination as '. $thumb .'.jpg';
}
```

Just be sure to prime the `thumbcount.txt` with a `1` so it has something to begin with.

Comment: The thing is, suppose I want to create social media website. so whenever the user upload any picture, it must be saved in the directory. So suppose user has uploaded total 5 pictures. so thumbnails which will be stored in the directory will be 1.jpg,2.jpg,.....,5.jpg. It is just for preserving the uniqueness for the image by giving them numeric name.

Comment: Right. You can go further with that as well and tack on a user_id to the image name, so they relate. Usually when I do images, I have a db entry which relates to them, all with unique id's and pathnames, which then link to users, or articles, and such. A whole lotta ways you can go with this ultimately :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the line responsible for saving image to file:

```
imagejpeg($imd,"saveimages/" . $_SESSION['sid'] . ".jpg");
```

You can update it to use `$fpath` instead of ,`$_SESSION['sid']`:

```
imagejpeg($imd, $fpath);
```

**But beware**, your path should end with **.jpg**.